# How can I use Google as OpenID provider after Google +?

Tags: google-plus, google-account, openid

For Google+ users, the [www.google.com/profiles/me](http://www.google.com/profiles/me) URL redirects to the user's Google+ profile. How can I use Google as my OpenID provider now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean you want to use your Google Account to login to sites using OpenID (like the Stack Exchange network) even if you don't have Google+ then you need to use the following URI:

`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`

If you are already signed in Google will recognise your account and perform the necessary actions.  If you aren't already signed in to Google, you will be prompted to sign in before you can continue.

Comment: I had already tried this URL on commandlinefu.com and it didn't work, but now I tried the same URL on a different app and it worked, so the URL is correct. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it on datahub.io and it didn't work.